# Extract features from a signal and save it in a file

Tags: matlab

I'm making a script in Matlab in order to extract features from an audio signal. This is the code:

```
clear;clc;

folder = dir('sonidos');
m = length(folder);

fileW = fopen('caracteristicas.txt','wt');

for i = 3:m
    file = strcat('sonidos/', folder(i).name);
    fprintf('Leyendo Archivo: %s \n', file);
    [y, Fs] = audioread(file);
    max = max(y);
    mean = mean(y);
    min = min(y);
    median = median(y);
    peak2peak = peak2peak(y);
    peak2rms = peak2rms(y);
    rms = rms(y);
    rssq = rssq(y);
    std = std(y);
    var = var(y);
    kurtosis = kurtosis(y);
    power = (norm(y)^2)/length(y);
    fprintf('Caracteristicas: %f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f \n', ...
            Fs, max, mean, min, median, peak2peak, peak2rms, rms, rssq, std, var, kurtosis, power);
    fprintf(fileW,'%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f \n', ...
                  Fs, max, mean, min, median, peak2peak, peak2rms, rms, rssq, std, var, kurtosis, power);
end

fclose(fileW);
```

Audio files are in the folder 'sonidos'. When I execute the code MatLab says:

```
Leyendo Archivo: sonidos/1.wav 
Caracteristicas: 22050.000000,0.352722,-0.000128,-0.435028,-0.000092,0.787750,17.550266,0.024788,6.027810,0.024787,0.000614,47.710490,0.000614 
Leyendo Archivo: sonidos/2.wav 
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Usually this error also provides a line number. Does it say anything like "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
Error in test (line 15) rms = rms(y);"?

Comment: No, it does not provide a line number. I tried comment each line and if I uncomment the line max = max(y), the error will take place. So, this script reads all files but can't extract any features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local variables overrides Matlab functions.

For example: `min = min(y);`, creates a local variable with the name `min`, and from now on, when you use `min`, the variable is used instead of `min` function.

Check the following:

```
clear;clc;

folder = dir('sonidos');
m = length(folder);

fileW = fopen('caracteristicas.txt','wt');

for i = 3:m
    file = strcat('sonidos/', folder(i).name);
    fprintf('Leyendo Archivo: %s \n', file);
    [y, Fs] = audioread(file);
    max0 = max(y);
    mean0 = mean(y);
    min0 = min(y);
    median0 = median(y);
    peak2peak0 = peak2peak(y);
    peak2rms0 = peak2rms(y);
    rms0 = rms(y);
    rssq0 = rssq(y);
    std0 = std(y);
    var0 = var(y);
    kurtosis0 = kurtosis(y);
    power0 = (norm(y)^2)/length(y);
    fprintf('Caracteristicas: %f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f \n', ...
        Fs, max0, mean0, min0, median0, peak2peak0, peak2rms0, rms0, rssq0, std0, var0, kurtosis0, power0);
    fprintf(fileW,'%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f \n', ...
              Fs, max0, mean0, min0, median0, peak2peak0, peak2rms0, rms0, rssq0, std0, var0, kurtosis0, power0);

end

fclose(fileW);
```

I modified your local variables names (just added `0` to the end of each).